# How does the data structure behind a language object (LANGSXP) look like in R?

Tags: r

For example the `call` field of a fitted model is of type Language Object.

Using the [Carseats data from ISL book](https://rdrr.io/cran/ISLR/man/Carseats.html).

```
> lm.fit <- lm(Sales ~ . + Income:Advertising + Price:Age, data = Carseats)
> lm.fit$call
lm(formula = Sales ~ . + Income:Advertising + Price:Age, data = Carseats)
```

Examples for accessing parts of the formula.

```
> lm.fit$call[2]
(Sales ~ . + Income:Advertising + Price:Age)()
> lm.fit$call[[2]]
Sales ~ . + Income:Advertising + Price:Age

> lm.fit$call[[2]][[3]][[3]]
Price:Age
```

How does the data structure look like in a Language Object for these lookups to work ?

---

This [document](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs) mentions briefly what a language object is

> Language objects (LANGSXP) are calls (including formulae and so on). Internally they are pairlists with first element a reference2 to the function to be called with remaining elements the actual arguments for the call (and with the tags if present giving the specified argument names). Although this is not enforced, many places in the code assume that the pairlist is of length one or more, often without checking.

This reminds me of a syntax tree like data structure but I am not sure.

In R, Is there a way to "raw print" the Language Object to see its structure without much formatting ? For example here, could one print the pair lists in some form ?

This [document](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing) also mentions the difference between `[` and `[[` index operators. But it would be nice to understand that difference specific to a Language Object.

Comment: I don't understand. What is unclear after reading the excerpt from the documentation? Are you confused because arguments to calls can be language objects?

Comment: Like most things in R, the languge object is just a list. You can coerce it to an actual list with `as.list(lm.fit$call)`. If you want to see the data in a more tree like form, try the `lobstr` package: `lobstr::ast(lm.fit$call)`